# Delete from source table then insert to target table if not exists

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Need to delete all rows from a source table , then insert the deleted rows to target table
ONLY if the deleted row doesn't exists yet in the target table.
Is it possible to issue using a single sql?

Code is the one I tried so far (though with error).
Thank You!

```
create table #Target (column01 varchar(100)  
        ,employee_number varchar(10)  
                    )
 Insert into #Target (column01, employee_number)  
values ('2','222')  

create table #Srs (column01 varchar(100)  
        ,employee_number varchar(10)  
                )  

 Insert into #Srs (column01, employee_number)  
 values ('1','111')  
    ,('2','222')  
    ,('3','333')  
        ,('4','444')  


;with cteTable as (Select column01, employee_number from #Srs)  
insert into #Target (column01, employee_number)  
select * from (Delete from cteTable output deleted.column01, deleted.employee_number)  t  
where   not exists (select 1  
        from #Target t1  
        where t1.employee_number = t.employee_number)
```

The 2,'222' should not be inserted into #Target on call to ";with cteTable.."

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6b7e/1)**

Comment: You may want to read up on the functionality of *MERGE*

Comment: Hi Raj, I haven't tried that approach as to where I should insert that Merge statement. Can i issue delete on source table using Merge?

Comment: By definition DML don't allow you to affect 2 tables in one statement. `MERGE` only affects one target table. The closest thing in *SQL Server* is `OUTPUT` clause but, it's for the full set of affected rows.

Comment: @LuisLL - With [composable DML](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/composable-dml) you can apply a filter to the rows but it doesn't allow subqueries in the `WHERE`

Answer (score 3):

Composable DML is quite limited.

You can do this if you change the definition of `#Target` though

```
CREATE TABLE #Target
  (
     column01        VARCHAR(100),
     employee_number VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON)
  )

INSERT INTO #Target
            (column01,
             employee_number)
VALUES      ('2',
             '222')

CREATE TABLE #Srs
  (
     column01        VARCHAR(100),
     employee_number VARCHAR(10)
  )

INSERT INTO #Srs
            (column01,
             employee_number)
VALUES      ('1', '111'),
            ('2', '222'),
            ('3', '333'),
            ('4', '444');

WITH cteTable
     AS (SELECT column01,
                employee_number
         FROM   #Srs)
INSERT INTO #Target
            (column01,
             employee_number)
SELECT * from (Delete from cteTable output deleted.column01, deleted.employee_number)  t
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. However, the target table contains primary key, an ID defined as int as Identity, other than the employee_number (w/c I did not include in the DDL).

Comment: @Elmer - You can use `employee_number VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON)` then (if the intention is that there should never be any duplicates). Apart from that it isn't possible to do this in a single statement (unless cheating with an `INSTEAD OF` trigger)

Comment: Hi Martin. Actually, I need to check on the duplicate entries in two columns (Sorry, not specified in my DDL). It's employee number and transaction_date column.

Comment: @Elmer - So `UNIQUE(employee_number, transaction_date) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON)` then. If this is intended to be unique it should be protected with a unique index anyway. But probably I would just `OUTPUT INTO` a table variable then use `MERGE` to only insert the desired rows.

Comment: Hi Martin. I followed your advised to Output into table variable then use MERGE. I Can't update the DDL of the existing table due to some company policy.  And that advised made the difference. Thanks for the help... :)

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be only one statement? If not you can use this.

```
begin transaction;

insert into Target(column01, employee_number)
select column01, employee_number
from Srs with (updlock, holdlock)
except
select column01, employee_number
from Target;

delete from Srs;

commit transaction;
```

Comment: Hi Mikael. Is it safe to do the delete? What if for a certain time, somebody issue insert on the Srs, I'm afraid that it well get deleted as well. Please advise

Comment: @Elmer Then you need to use a transaction. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Mikael. That helped a lot on possible options.